# When an addon domain is created it automatically generates a sub domain, why?

Tags: dns, seo, subdomain, cpanel

As i said in the title. Why when i create an addon domain it automatically creates a sub domain and to further explore the question how does this affect the SEO of the sites that share the same hosting and if the effect is bad? Is there anyway to lessen it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about behaviour of search engine services / SEO. -- This question might be appropriate on [webmasters.se].